# The ideal generated by $x_\beta, h_\beta - \lambda(h_\beta), \beta \in \Phi^+,$ is the same as the ideal generated by taking all $\beta \in \Delta$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a semisimple Lie algebra with root system $\Phi$, Cartan subalgebra $H$, positive roots $\Phi^+$ and simple roots $\Delta$. Denote by $U(L)$ its universal enveloping algebra.

Fix an arbitrary $\lambda \in H^*$ and a system of generators  $\{x_\gamma,y_\gamma,h_\gamma: \gamma \in \Phi\}$ of $L$ such that the subalgebra generated by $x_\gamma, y_\gamma, h_\gamma$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

> Let $I(\lambda)$ be the ideal of $U(L)$ generated by  $x_\beta, h_\beta -\lambda(h_\beta).1$ for all $\beta \in \Phi^+$ and $\tilde I(\lambda)$ be the ideal of $U(L)$ generated by $x_\alpha, h_\alpha - \lambda(h_\alpha).1$ for all $\alpha \in \Delta$. Prove that $I(\lambda) = \tilde I(\lambda)$.

Since the simple roots $\Delta$ are positive, $I(\lambda)$ contains all the generators of $\tilde I(\lambda)$, so $\tilde I(\lambda) \subseteq I(\lambda)$.

For the other direction, let $\beta \in \Phi^+$. All we have to do is to prove that $x_\beta$ and $h_\beta-\lambda(h_\beta).1$ lie in $\tilde I(\lambda)$. By some previous result in our book, there are $\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_s \in \Delta$ such that $\beta = \alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_s $ with each partial sum $\alpha_1+\cdots +\alpha_i \in \Phi^+, 1\leq i \leq s.$ We prove by induction on $s$ that $x_\beta \in \tilde I(\lambda)$, the case $s=1$ being clear. Since $L_\beta = [L_{\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{s-1}}, L_{\alpha_s}],$ then $x_\beta = c. [x_{\alpha_1+\cdots + \alpha_{s-1}}~,  x_{\alpha_s}]$ for some $c\neq 0$. Now the induction hyphotesis applied to $x_{\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{s-1}}$ and the inclusion $L\subseteq U(L)$  assures that $x_\beta \in \tilde I({\lambda})$.

**I can't prove** that $h_\beta-\lambda(h_\beta).1$ lies in this ideal. Since $h_\beta = [x_\beta,y_\beta]$ and $x_\beta$ had seen to be in $\tilde I(\lambda)$, we have that $h_\beta \in \tilde I(\lambda)$. But the sum of $-\lambda(h_\beta).1$  with $h_\beta$ is actually bothering me and I am not sure how to finish the argument.

Any help?

Comment: I guess $I(\lambda)$ is a *left* ideal of $U(L)$. If it is a two-sided ideal, it would be whole $U(L)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Delta \subset \Phi $ is a base, $\Delta$ spans $H^*$. Recall that $H^*$ is identified with $H$ via $\lambda \mapsto  t_\lambda$, where $t_\lambda$ is the unique element of $H$ such that $\kappa(t_\lambda, h)=\lambda(h)$ for all $h \in H$. Here $\kappa$ is the Killing form. For any $\alpha \in \Phi$, we have $h_\alpha = 2t_\alpha / \kappa(t_\alpha, t_\alpha)$. Thus $$h_\alpha - \lambda(h_\alpha).1 = \frac{2}{\kappa(t_\alpha, t_\alpha)}(t_\alpha - \lambda(t_\alpha).1)$$
in $U(L)$.

Now write $\beta = \alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_s$. Then $t_{\alpha_i} - \lambda(t_{\alpha_i}).1 \in \tilde{I}(\lambda)$ for all $i$ since they are scalar multiples of $h_{\alpha_i}-\lambda(h_{\alpha_i}).1 \in \tilde{I}(\lambda)$. Observe that $t_\beta = t_{\alpha_1} + \dots + t_{\alpha_s}$, which implies $t_\beta - \lambda(t_\beta).1 \in \tilde{I}(\lambda)$. It follows that $h_\beta-\lambda(h_\beta).1 \in \tilde{I}(\lambda)$.